# Select input field with name as array field

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I wanted to select the text field based on condition, for example:

```
if only text field name = sname[] than only put value in it.
```

For this I used

```
<input type="text" name="sname[]" />

where name = sname;

//For each name type field in extra add contact module if that i visible.
    $('input[name=' + name + '[]]').each(function() { 

});
```

But I'm not able to get inside of it. Please suggest how to get into the selection.

Answer (score 16):

```
$('input[name="' + name + '[]"]').each(function() {
    $(this).val('Some value');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for each loop, you could do it like :

```
$('input[name="field_name[]"]').val('Some value');
```

Hope this helps.