# How to get all inputs with a certain name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a bunch of text inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" name="option[]" value="option 1" onBlur="outputOptions()">
<input type="text" name="option[]" value="option 2" onBlur="outputOptions()">
<input type="text" name="option[]" value="option 3" onBlur="outputOptions()">
```

I want to be able to get the values of all of the inputs, so I tried doing this:

```
function outputOptions()
{
    console.log("inside outputOptions");

        $("input[name=option]").each(
            function() {
                console.log("option value: " + $(this).value);
            }
        );
}
```

On my site the result is that when I click in and out of a text input I see "inside outputOptions," but none of the text input values are printed out.

What am I doing wrong?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6zguZ/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000368/select-input-field-with-name-as-array-field

Comment: 1. `option != option[]` 2. `$(this).value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the value the wrong way:

```
    console.log("option value: "  + this.value);
```

If you *really* want to use jQuery, you'd do:

```
    console.log("option value: " + $(this).val());
```

but there's no reason to do that.

You also need to select using the actual name:

```
 $('input[name="option[]"]').each(
```

It's not an error for a jQuery selection to match no elements, so you get no error for something like that.

Comment: `input[name="option[]"]` will generate a syntax error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=option[]]`

Comment: @FrançoisWahl hmm give me a sec ... no, I don't get a syntax error for that.  Are you putting the name in double-quotes, like I did?

Comment: Yes indeed, you are correct. My bad, I did not notice the quotes you had. In that case my answer is completely redundant. +1 to yours though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName("option[]"), l = inputs.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    console.log(inputs[i].value);
}
```

EDIT: Here's a [speed test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-js-name) to show why this is better than jQuery.

Comment: This answer reminds me of the article on jQuery in the Web Designer issue 202 - page 41. To quote: `It wouldn't be uncommon to read that it is better to use vanilla for loops over $.each or that it is better practice to use getElementByClassName over the jQuery sizzle engine because it is faster. The problem with tips like that is that they take the idea of pre-optimization to an extreme and don't account for the various browser inconsistencies - the thing that jQuery fixed for us. Running tests, observing savings of a few milliseconds over 1k repetitions is not a reason to abandon jQuery.`

Comment: It goes on to say `Your time is much better invested in tweaking parts of your application that will actually make a difference, such as the size of your images for instance.` -- No offense intended at all, I just got a complete flashback of that article when I read this answer. Non-the-less, +1 on the answer as it also is a valid working solution.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Sure, I understand. But `getElementsByName`, `length` and `for` have been around and standardized since the very first version of JavaScript.